# Updating ruby from 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

How to Update ruby from 2.0.0 to the newest one for my mac book air?  Ive tried most CLI tutorials and having a few errors which doesn't allow me to download rails either.  this is the error I'm getting when trying to update using rbenv:

```
 $ rbenv install 2.3.1 
Downloading ruby-2.1.3.tar.bz2... -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.3.tar.bz2 Installing ruby-2.1.3...  
WARNING: ruby-2.1.3 is nearing its end of life. It only receives critical security updates, no bug fixes.
BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.6 using ruby-build 20160602)
Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/6h/xq5sgstd3ynfkc4qcp53m0dh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20160822200825.84956
Results logged to /var/folders/6h/xq5sgstd3ynfkc4qcp53m0dh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20160822200825.84956.log
Last 10 log lines: 
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [main.o] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''    
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin 
make: *** [dmydln.o] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean ruby 2.3.1? 2.1.3 has a warning.

I would recommend using homebrew as well.

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.3.1
rbenv global 2.3.1
ruby -v
gem install bundler
```

More info: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan

Comment: that is what I was following and at the first rbenv  install 2.3.1 is where my error showed up.

Comment: I think what is holding me back is the active support which needs ruby 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

In my case installation was crashing because I reinstalled Xcode recently and forgot to install command tools.

After running

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

I successfully installed Ruby using `rbenv`.